# How to use RenderListDataAsStream with filters like startswith,endswith etc in Sharepoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint, rest

I have been trying to do a SharePoint List Search with a search box containing the search term. I'm currently using RenderListDataAsStream API provided by sharepoint with **InplaceSearchQuery** as my current working solution. But this searches all the columns but not for a single column. How Do I achieve this functionality ?

This is the API I'm currently using

**/_api/web/GetList('TestList')/RenderListDataAsStream?InplaceSearchQuery=item%201**

I would like to search for a particular item a particular column in the test list rather than looking for the item in all the columns

Comment: Please, share the code example.

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo I've updated the code example